# How to be able to resize the below np array, i seem to have a map object and it is not allowing me to resize it

Tags: python, numpy

How to be able to resize the below np array, i seem to have a map object and it is not allowing me to resize it
example:
say if the input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
output must be of the form [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]]

```
    import numpy as np
    value= map(int, input().split())
    myarray=np.array(value)
    print(np.reshape(myarray, (3,3)))
```

is my code and the error that i receive is as attached in the screenshot[image: error]

Comment: Please post your exception as text. While you've already received an answer (which you should select), it is up to all of us to maintain this site for future readers. This includes making it searchable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your map object to a list first

```
myarray=np.array(list(value))
```

For some reason, np.array will not convert a map object to a list for you.

Comment: `np.array` does not do this kind of conversion for anyone.  OK, there's a minor historical exception, `np.array(range(5))` does work.

Comment: @hpaulj. Is it specifically a range object, or all sequences that this works for?

Comment: @Mad, I think `range` is the exception that proves the rule.  In py2 it produced a list.